# Getting an exception when adding audio to mediaplayer

Tags: java, audio, javafx, fxml

So after I added the images that I wanted to add, I went and tried to add audio like this

```
 <MediaPlayer fx:id="gameIntro" autoPlay="true"volume="0.1">
  <media>
      <Media source="@AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3" />
  </media>
 </MediaPlayer>
```

but that didn't work.

Error that relates to the problem

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MillionaireTriviaGame/dist/run30649974/MillionaireTriviaGame.jar!/millionairetriviagame/MenulayoutFXML.fxml:18

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2547)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
at millionairetriviagame.MillionaireTriviaGame.start(MillionaireTriviaGame.java:17)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/1270092040.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/355629945.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1753953479.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1915503092.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,49]
Message: Element type "MediaPlayer" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
... 22 more
 Exception running application millionairetriviagame.MillionaireTriviaGame
 Java Result: 1
```

My FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

 <StackPane fx:id="MainMenu" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.MenulayoutFXMLController">
  <ImageView>
  <image>
     <Image url="@ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg"/>
  </image>
 </ImageView>

 <MediaPlayer fx:id="gameIntro" autoPlay="true"volume="0.1">
  <media>
      <Media source="@AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3" />
  </media>
 </MediaPlayer>

<VBox fx:id="MainMenuLayout" spacing="20" alignment="TOP_CENTER" > 
<ImageView>
    <image>
         <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png"/>
    </image>
 </ImageView>
 </VBox>
  </StackPane>
```

My main Class

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{  
@Override
public void start(Stage menuStage) throws Exception 
{
    Parent object = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MenulayoutFXML.fxml"));

    Scene menuScene = new Scene(object);

    menuStage.setTitle("Let's play who wants to be a millionaire");
    menuStage.setScene(menuScene);
    menuStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

A screenshot of my project directory

[image: Project Directory]

---

### EDIT

I tried loading a Media into the mediaplayer using the following code

```
@Override 
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
    Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3").toExternalForm());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(gameIntroTheme);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1); 
}
```

It doesn't work and gives an `NullpointerException` and a `javafx.fxml.loadException`. But if I move the audio files folder outside of the `src` folder and the do this

```
 Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(new File("AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3").toURI().toString());
```

The program works. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to add a [`MediaView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) to the fxml if you want to create a videoplayer, or do not add anything if you just want to play audio. Inside your controller, create instances of MediaPlayer and Media, load media and add them to MediaView, if required.

A FXML example can be [found here](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/MediaPlayerFX/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/ita/fxml/mediaplayer.fxml). The corresponding controller can be [found here](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/MediaPlayerFX/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ita/controller/MediaPlayerController.java).

Comment: Well I think it is best if I tell you how I want to implement these audio files and then take it from there. I plan to add other audio files later on and this audio("gameIntroTheme.mp3") file in particular will only be played in the background(They will be all played in the background actually so I have no need for mediaview) for the entire duration unless the user goes to another screen. In which case it will never be played again after that. I then planned to add in another audio file that will play forever until the user returns the main menu or exits the program.

Comment: You don't need a MediaView. Load an audio file in a Media, initialize a MediaPlayer and assign media to it and play the player. When you go to another screen, stop the mediaplayer -> load the other audio into Media -> set it to MediaPlayer and play.

Comment: Alright this is my attempt. `@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
         Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3").toExternalForm());
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(gameIntroTheme);
         mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
         mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
    }     It doesn't work mainly because it gets a nullpointerException and a javafx.fxml.loadException`

Comment: The path for the file looks about right(it's in the same location as image files) so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Well If I move the audio files folder outside of the src folder and the do this Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(new File("AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3").toURI().toString()); The program works but why doesn't the other method work. Please explain itachi

Comment: The first one should have worked. I am not sure what went wrong. Try creating a MCVE.

Comment: Well why does the other method work and not the other? Maybe we should figure out that.

Comment: The other method works because you are reading it as a `File` and not as a resource. Though this method works now, it will fail, it you have packaged your application as a jar.

Comment: Exactly and I don't want that(I later plan to make to make this program into a jar file so this part is crucial).

Comment: If the path that I'm getting the mp3 from is getting null, then something must be wrong with the path that I'm using. Take a look at the project directory screenshot as I have updated it with a new picture if that helps.

Comment: Try replacing the path with `getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.mp3");`. If this doesn't work, you can trying running one of [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499261/how-to-pause-resume-a-song-in-javafx/29510308#29510308) by replacing the path.

Comment: I'm getting an illegal character escape(\u200c) and that uri can't be converted to string.

Answer (score 0):

so this is the answer

```
Media gameIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.mp3").toExternalForm());
```

Make sure that if you're are doing it in this case that the extension is the same as the file that you're working with.

credit to kiheru and itachi for helping me figure it out.